# Why should we not face our backs towards god?

Tags: belief, karma, tradition, customs

At a temple, I usually see the *pujari* often reminding people that they should face towards god. He also said that facing our backs towards god is classified as a sin.

I would think that facing our backs towards god is disrespectful, but would it be a sin? What if it is just an accident?